# Celery: How to allow queueing "duplicate" tasks, but disallow working on "duplicate tasks"?

Tags: celery, celery-task

We're already using [celery-singleton](https://github.com/steinitzu/celery-singleton) (similar to [celery-once](https://github.com/cameronmaske/celery-once)) to disallow *queueing* duplicate tasks, but now we have a case where we would like to allow queuing duplicate tasks but disallow *working on* duplicate tasks at the same time.

Example case:
We have the job message `{area_id: 42, item_id: 1}` which is currently being worked on. For domain-specific reasons we would like to only have one task being worked on at the same time for any given `area_id`. The next message in the task queue is `{area_id: 42, item_id: 2}`. We would like this second task to wait until the first one is completed successfully. A task for a different `area_id`, e.g. `{area_id: 23, item_id: 1}` should be allowed to be executed at the same time by a different worker.

Are there any plugins to Celery similar to celery-singleton / celery-once that will easily allow us to accomplish this? I ask before trying to implement this myself in case a library already exists (which escaped my googling).